# induced subgraphs of odd graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> For $d\geq 3,$ the odd graph $O_d$ has vertices that are the $(d-1)$-subsets of $\{1,2,\cdots, 2d-1\}.$ Two vertices $v, v'$ are adjacent in $O_d$ iff $v\cap v' = \emptyset.$ Prove that the odd graph $O_d$ has $C_6$ as an induced subgraph and $C_{2d-1}$ as an induced subgraph for $d\geq 3.$

I know that $O_3$ is isomorphic to the Petersen graph and it's not hard to find a cycle of length $6$ in $O_3.$ However, I'm not sure how to find a general algorithm to find a cycle of length $6$ in $O_d$ or of length $2d-1.$ I know I need to consider a general cycle $(c_1c_2\cdots c_6c_1)$, where $c_2,\cdots, c_6$ are all adjacent to $2$ vertices each (e.g. $c_2\cap c_1 = \emptyset, c_2 \cap c_3 = \emptyset,$ etc.). I also know that the odd graph $O_d$ also has ${2d-1\choose d-1}$ vertices and ${2d-1\choose d-1}\frac{d}2$ edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $(2d-1)$-cycle think of the elements of $[2d-1]=\{1,\ldots,2d-1\}$ arranged clockwise in a circle in numerical order. Let $c_1=\{1,\ldots,d-1\}$ and $c_2=\{d+1,\ldots,2d-1\}$. Now shift each of these sets one space clockwise and let $c_3=\{2,\ldots,d\}$ and $c_4=\{d+2,\ldots,2d-1\}\cup\{1\}$, where $c_3$ is adjacent to $c_2$, and of course $c_4$ is adjacent to $c_3$. Repeat this process to get $c_{2k-1}$ and $c_{2k}$ for $k=1,\ldots,d-1$; you’ll find that

$$c_{2d-3}=\{d-1,\ldots,2d-3\}\,,$$

and

$$c_{2d-2}=\{2d-1\}\cup\{1,\ldots,d-2\}\,.$$

Then $c_{2d-1}=\{d,\ldots, 2d-2\}$, and $c_{2d}=c_1$ again, completing a cycle of length $2d-1$.

For a $6$-cycle when $d>3$, start with a $6$-cycle in $O_3$, say $c_1,\ldots,c_6,c_1$. Let $A=\{6,\ldots,d+2\}$ and $B=\{d+3,\ldots,2d-1\}$; note that $|A|=|B|=d-3$. Now let

$$c_k'=\begin{cases}
c_k\cup A,&\text{if }k\text{ is odd}\\
c_k\cup B,&\text{if }k\text{ is even;}
\end{cases}$$

$c_1',\ldots,c_6',c_1'$ is then a $6$-cycle in $O_d$.